# Query related to == in case of Wrapper classes

Tags: java

I have been playing with == in wrapper classes. There's some weird thing that I encountered.

```
Integer i1 = 3;
Integer i2 = 3;

if(i1 != i2)
{
    System.out.println("i1 and i2 are not equal");     // if condition returns false in this case
}
```

which is working perfectly fine as far as my knowledge is concerned.

whereas, If I instantiate wrapper with

```
Integer i1 = 1000;
Integer i2 = 1000;


if(i1 != i2)
{
        System.out.println("i1 and i2 are not equal");    // if condition returns true in here
}
```

Then I am getting confused with the dual behavior of JVM with respect to the different values assigned to wrapper.
Why is this happening so? Please share your thought on this.

Thanks

Comment: dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638023/strange-wrapper-classes-behavior-with-and?rq=1

Comment: I don't understand the question.`// if condition returns true in here` in particular, after `i1 != i2`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `!i1.equals(i2)`

Comment: Good answer beside solution also *explains* problem.