# Difference between double and Double in comparison

Tags: java, double

I know that `Double` is a a wrapper class, and it wraps `double` number. Today, I have seen another main difference :

```
double a = 1.0;
double b = 1.0;
Double c = 1.0;
Double d = 1.0;
System.out.println(a == b);  // true
System.out.println(c == d);  // false
```

So strange with me !!!

So, if we use `Double`, each time, we must do something like this :

```
private static final double delta = 0.0001;
System.out.println(Math.abs(c-d) < delta);
```

I cannot explain why Double make directly comparison wrong. Please explain for me.

Comment: Use `c.equals(d)` instead of `==`. `==` only checks references.

Comment: @Baz Ah, I understand. Double is a class. It will compare object rather than compare value. This problem likes when we do with `String`. should use `equals` instead of `==` :)

Comment: Another difference is Double allow null value but double not.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`c` and `d` are technically two different objects and `==` operator compares only references.

```
c.equals(d)
```

is better as it compares values, not references. But still not ideal. Comparing floating-point values directly should always take some error (epsilon) into account (`Math.abs(c - d) < epsilon`).

Note that:

```
Integer c = 1;
Integer d = 1;
```

here comparison would yield `true`, but that's more complicated (`Integer` internal caching, described in [JavaDoc of `Integer.valueOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(int))):

> This method will always cache values in the range -128 to 127, inclusive, and may cache other values outside of this range.

Why `valueOf()`? Because this method is implicitly used to implement autoboxing:

```
Integer c = Integer.valueOf(1);
Integer d = Integer.valueOf(1);
```

## See also

- [Weird Integer boxing in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130311)
- [How to properly compare two Integers in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514910)

Comment: Oh. I have understand. this problem likes when we do with string class. But your second example is interesting. Can you tell me why it true when do with integer :)

Comment: @hqt: check out the links in *See also* section of my answer.

Comment: @hqt you can call it integer pool. Sized <-128,127> - All Integer within this range are equal using both `equals()` and `==`

Comment: Oh. Nice link :) I don't know why many people here know this kind of knowledge. I don't see this in any Java book before. (about integer pol :) )

Comment: I suppose Jon remembers this better :), so the range is from -128 to 127 (not -256 -> 255 as I wrote earlier). With a total numbers of 256, which is exactly **byte** range.

Comment: @hqt Try some book preparing for SCJP / OCPJP certificate. You'll find it pretty fast ;) Or just read Effective Java (I think it's there too)

Comment: Be *VERY* careful comparing floating-point numbers.  The subject is a mine-field.  See http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm and http://floating-point-gui.de/references/ and references therein.

Answer (score 6):

When applied to expressions of a class type, `==` will *always* perform a reference comparison ([JLS section 15.21.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.3)). So this line:

```
System.out.println(c == d);
```

is checking whether `c` and `d` refer to the same objects. Auto-boxing in Java always (I believe) creates a new object for `float` and `double` (the situation is more complicated for integral types<sup>1</sup>). Therefore `c` and `d` refer to different objects, and so it prints `false`.

If you want to compare *objects* for equality, you need to call `equals` explicitly:

```
System.out.println(c.equals(d));
```

With `double`, it's using numeric equality instead - as specified in [section 15.21.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.1). Hence the difference in behaviour.

---

<sup>1</sup> For integral autoboxing, "small" values are cached - so autoboxing 5 (say) will return the same reference every time. The definition of "small" is implementation-specific, but it's guaranteed within the range -128 to 127. See the bottom of [section 5.1.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7) for details.

Comment: About integer cache, can you tell me why you can know this ? I don't see this stuff in any java book I have read. ( and I don't think you learn all Java spec :D)

Comment: @hqt Even if you don't know all of the spec by heart, after a while you know most of it. And it is a good practice that whenever you see something that you don't know how it works you go and check the specs and / or the source. The new knowledge makes you a better developer and reduces the risk for bugs.

Answer (score 4):

Use `equals()` to checks the equality of 2 objects. `==` checks if the 2 references refer to the same object in the memory.

Answer (score 2):

Content checking is only reliable for `==` when checking primitive types. For objects types it is always better to use the `equals` method:

```
c.equals(d)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Difference between `==` and `equals`**

using `==` on primitive data types is not the same as using it on object reference data types.

1. On primitive data types `==` is used as `equals`.
2. for object reference data types `==` refers to their references. Thus
   what the object points to in memory.

**Consider case 1**

```
    double d1 = 10.00;
    double d2 =10.00;
    System.out.println(d1 == d2);
```

*output is *   `true`

[image]

**case 2: `==` reference data types**

```
    Double d1 = 10.00;
    Double d2 =10.00;
    System.out.println(d1 == d2);
```

*output is * `false`

[image]

d1 and d2 have different memory references.

to check the validity of this consider the following code

```
    Double d1 = 10.00;
    Double d2 = d1;
    System.out.println(d1 == d2);
```

This will print `true` since d1 and d2 point to the same memory reference.

**Therefore**

*`Java` uses `==` to compare **primitives** and for checking if two variables refer to the same **object***

***`equals'***

is used for checking if two `objects` are equivalent.

it also depends on the implementation of the object it is being called on. For `Strings`, `equals()` checks the characters inside of it.

```
    Double d1 = 10.00;
    Double d2 = 10.00;
    System.out.println(d1.equals(d2));
```

prints  `true` since it looks what's inside the d1 and d2.

**case 1** will not compile

[image]