# "double, Double, HashSet" in Java

Tags: java, hashmap, hashset, type-conversion

Please see the code below.

"Double"(upper D) is used in HashSet, and "double" is used for x1, x2 and x3. After x1 is added to the HashSet, x2 cannot be added, but x3 can! Why??????

Thanks in advance :)

```
HashSet<Double> hs = new HashSet<Double>();
double x1, x2, x3;

x1 = (double)0/1;
System.out.println(hs.add(x1)); //true

x2 = (double)0/2;
System.out.println(hs.add(x2)); //false

x3 = (double)0/-1;
System.out.println(hs.add(x3)); //true
```

---

And if you add "0.0 +" for x1, x2 and x3, the result is as follows.

```
x1 = 0.0 + (double)0/1;
System.out.println(hs.add(x1)); //true

x2 = 0.0 + (double)0/2;
System.out.println(hs.add(x2)); //false

x3 = 0.0 + (double)0/-1;
System.out.println(hs.add(x3)); //false
```

Comment: Sets do not allow duplicates. You are passing 0, 0 , -0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this to understand difference:

```
HashSet<Double> hs = new HashSet<Double>();
double x1, x2, x3;

x1 = (double)0/1;
System.out.println(x1 + " "+ hs.add(x1)); //true

x2 = (double)0/2;
System.out.println(x2 + " " + hs.add(x2)); //false

x3 = (double)0/-1;
System.out.println(x3 + " " + hs.add(x3)); //true
```

Basically [doubles](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) are signed and 0/-1 will be evaluated as -0.0 instead of 0.0 by x1 or x2.

Comment: Thank you so much, I understand the difference now!

Comment: @YilongWang, if the answer is sufficient to you then you should accept the answer. When other users have the same question as you they will easier see a correct answer.

Comment: @Maksym you need to refer this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771328/java-signed-zero-and-boxing

Answer (score 0):

`HashSet<E>` only allows unique values, unlike `List<E>`.

`x1 = (double)0/1;` equals to `0.0`, same as `x2 = 0.0 + (double)0/2;`. While `x3 = (double)0/-1;` equals to `-0.0`. This is why you can add the first and third element but not the second.

When to use HashSet then? What is the pro of it over `List`?

That has already been answered here [HashSet vs. List performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150750/hashset-vs-list-performance), which I recommend you to read.

Some minor things of your code.

- I see no reason to mix Double and double, stick to one for easier reading.
  [Java : different double and Double in comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12226757/java-different-double-and-double-in-comparison)
- Normally one would write it as `Set<Double> hs = new HashSet<>();`
  Note that it is only supported to use the Diamond Operator in Java 7+. You can read more of it here [What is the point of the diamond operator in Java 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166966/what-is-the-point-of-the-diamond-operator-in-java-7).