# Why can't I compare two numbers Double class Java using operator "=="?

Tags: java

I have tried to make a simple code to compare numbers if is equal using  Double class. This is my simple code:

```
BufferedReader bfr= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    Double number1;
    Double number2;
    System.out.println("Ask for first number:");
    number1 = Double.parseDouble(bfr.readLine());
    System.out.println("Ask for second number:");
    number2 =  Double.parseDouble(bfr.readLine());
    
    if(number1==number2) {
        System.out.println("These numbers are equals!");
        System.out.println(number1);
        System.out.println(number2);
    }else {
        System.out.println("They're differents!");
        System.out.println(number1);
        System.out.println(number2);
    }
```

When I use "int" instead Double and the operator "==" it works fine but when I use "Double" it shows me  they are different numbers even the same numbers are entered. I've tried to use Object.equals() method it works fine but I want to know why "Double" class  does not admit operator "==".

Comment: Decimal processors cannot do exact representations of floating point numbers but rather only close approximations

Comment: I seem to recall there's a compare() function for comparing doubles

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: this is not actually a problem about the numerical approximation. If you parse `0.1` twice you'll get the same `double` value. But OP is comparing two `Double` wrapper objects for object identity!

Comment: @JoachimSauer: ayyyy, my bad. Then `Double.compare(...)` or `Double#equals(...)` would be needed

Comment: @JoachimSauer: a better duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12226757/difference-between-double-and-double-in-comparison

Answer (score 2):

The important difference between `int` and `Double` here is *not* the floating point nature (though that can make computations behave in unexpected ways), but the fact that `int` is a primitive type and `Double` is a reference type (a wrapper around `double`).

When you compare reference type values using `==` you check for object identity. I.e. the expression `number1 == number2` means "do the variables `number1` and `number2` reference the exact same object", which is almost certainly not what you want.

The solution, as you found is to use `number1.equals(number2)`.

Another workaround would be to switch from `Double` (the wrapper) to `double` the primitive type. Usually you can just assign one to the other and the appropriate autoboxing/autounboxing will handle the conversion.