# Clarification regarding Integer comparison?

Tags: java, integer, autoboxing, value-of

```
class Demo{
public static void main(String[] args) {  
     Integer i = Integer.valueOf(127);  
     Integer j = Integer.valueOf(127);        

     System.out.println(i==j);  

     Integer k = Integer.valueOf(128);  
     Integer l = Integer.valueOf(128);        

     System.out.println(k==l);  
  }  
}
```

The first print statement prints true whereas the second one prints false.Why?
Please explain in detail.

Comment: This is already discussed here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130311/weird-integer-boxing-in-java

and here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514910/when-comparing-two-integers-in-java-does-auto-unboxing-occur

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because Integer caching.

From [java language specification 5.1.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7)

```
If the value p being boxed is true, false, a byte, or a char in the range 
\u0000 to \u007f, or an int or short number between -128 and 127 (inclusive), 
then let r1 and r2 be the results of any two boxing conversions of p. 
It is always the case that r1 == r2.
```

Ideally, boxing a given primitive value p, would **always yield an identical reference**.

```
Integer i = Integer.valueOf(127);  
Integer j = Integer.valueOf(127);
```

Both `i` and `j` point to *same object.* As  the value is less than 127.

```
Integer k = Integer.valueOf(128);  
Integer l = Integer.valueOf(128);
```

Both `k` & `l` point to *different objects.* As the value is greater than 127.
As, you are checking the object references using `==` operator, you are getting different results.

---

**Update**

You can use `equals()` method to get the same result

```
System.out.println(i.equals(j));//equals() compares the values of objects not references  
System.out.println(k.equals(l));//equals() compares the values of objects not references
```

Output is

```
true
true
```

1. `==` operator checks the actual object references.
2. [`equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) checks the values(contents) of objects.

---

**Answer to comment**

You have,

```
Integer i = Integer.valueOf(127);
```

Here new object is created & reference is assigned to `i`

```
Integer j = Integer.valueOf(127); //will not create new object as it already exists
```

Due to integer caching (number between -128 to 127) previously created object reference is assigned to `j`, then `i` and `j` point to same objects.

Now consider,

```
Integer p = Integer.valueOf(127); //create new object 
Integer q = Integer.valueOf(126); //this also creates new object as it does not exists
```

Obviously both checks using `==` operator and `equals()` method will result `false`. As both are different references and have different vales.

Comment: can you please elaborate on "i and j point to same reference" and "k and l point to different reference"

Comment: @PrasoonMishra: Please see updated post. I hope your doubt will clear. After reading updated post have any doubts let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
   i==j
```

is `true`  for values between `-128` and `127`  due to integer caching.

From  [language spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7)

> If the value p being boxed is true, false, a byte, or a char in the range \u0000 to \u007f, or an int or short number between -128 and 127 (inclusive), then let r1 and r2 be the results of any two boxing conversions of p. It is always the case that r1 == r2.

```
   Integer i = Integer.valueOf(127);   // new object
   Integer j = Integer.valueOf(127);   //cached object reference 
   Integer k = Integer.valueOf(128);   // new object
   Integer l = Integer.valueOf(128);   // new object
```

So `i` and `j` are pointing to same reference because of value 127.

Where as `k` and `l`  pointing to difference references, because their value `>127`

**There is a reason mentioned in docs for this behaviour:**

The behavior will be the desired one, without imposing an undue performance penalty, especially on small devices. Less memory-limited implementations might

Answer (score 0):

valueOf returns an Integer Object. Integer is a wrapper class for int. For your case,

Integer == Integer compares the actual object reference, where int == int will compare the values.

As already stated, values -128 to 127 are cached, so the same objects are returned for those.

If outside that range, separate objects will be created so the reference will be different.

You fix it by following way if you want same result for your both cases:

- Make the types int
- Cast the types to int or
- Use .equals()