# Comparison with operator ==, how does it work?

Tags: java, comparison, comparison-operators

I came up with the following question in a Java test:

```
import java.awt.Button;
class CompareReference 
{
    public static void main(String [] args) 
    {
        float f = 42.0f;
        float [] f1 = new float[2];
        float [] f2 = new float[2];
        float [] f3 = f1;
        long x = 42;
        f1[0] = 42.0f;
    }
}
```

which three statements are true?

1. `f1 == f2`
2. `f1 == f3`
3. `f2 == f1[1]`
4. `x == f1[0]`
5. `f == f1[0]`

I need to choose only 3 statements.

Well, `1` is obviously false because we'were comparing two different references, `2` is obviously true because the references are the same. But I don't know about primitives. What I'm confused by is that if we compare `Integer`s in range -128 to 127 they are caching. Related [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130311/weird-integer-boxing-in-java). Is there something about primitives, some narrow cases?

I was looking for how it works in the `JLS 8` but didn't find anything useful.

Comment: that is when it autobox, there is no autoboxing here, it is just plain primitive value comparission

Comment: indeed. also you could just run a program that outputs the true/false value of the above.

Comment: The third expression doesn't even compile.

Comment: Why `import java.awt.Button;` ? :D

Comment: *"What I'm confused by is that if we compare Integers in range -128 to 127 they are caching."* Huh? First: There are no `Integer`s in the above. Second: "Caching"?!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, it is. What's wrong? From the JLS: _If the value p being boxed is an integer literal of type int between -128 and 127 inclusive (§3.10.1), or the boolean literal true or false (§3.10.3), or a character literal between '\u0000' and '\u007f' inclusive (§3.10.4), then let a and b be the results of any two boxing conversions of p. It is always the case that a == b._

Comment: @St.Antario: There are no boxing conversions anywhere in your code.

Comment: @St.Antario - Yes, `Integer` instances between `-128` to `127` are cached and reused. So, `==` will work on them (because the same instances are reused). The range can be changed as well. Next, as *NPE* points out, your code has no relation with this question.

Comment: @TheLostMind I mean can compariso of floats be tricky? Or we always have that a == b iff they have the same primitive values?

Comment: @St.Antario - Yes. Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088216/whats-wrong-with-using-to-compare-floats-in-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comparison 3 will not compile: it tries to compare an array to a scalar.

Comparisons 4 and 5 involve primitives and are done by value. There are no references or autoboxing involved. Therefore the following is not relevant here:

> What I'm confused by is that if we compare `Integers` in range -128 to 127 they are caching.

Since `42` can be represented exactly as a `float`, comparison 4 will return `true`.

Comparison 5 will also return `true` since it's comparing two identical `float` values.

Answer (score 1):

2, 4 and 5 are `true`.

Although remember that comparing floats by `==` might be tricky, it's safer to do this like this:

`Math.abs(float1 - float2) < epsilon`

where `epsilon` is some small number (precision).