# Autoboxing in java?

Tags: java, autoboxing

I found that when **x** and **y** are autoboxed to **400**the output is **Not same** but when **x** and **y** are autoboxed to **40** they are coming as same.Why??

```
public class Demo1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
         Integer x = 400, y = 400;
         if (x == y)
            System.out.println("Same");
         else
            System.out.println("Not Same");
    }
}
```

Comment: @Paul - not it isn't.

Comment: this issue here is obviously not autoboxing, but the comparison via `==`. `Object` are usually compared via `equals`

Comment: @AbubakkarRangara That is what my doubt is.I know the difference b/w == and equals().

Comment: @StephenC i know the title isn't exactly helpfull with this one. But the topic is just the same. Comparing Objects

Comment: @Paul - no it isn't.  This question is about the caching behavior of the primitive wrapper types.  Comparing objects is a broader question ... and the answer you proposed as a duplicate isn't even about that.

Comment: I could not believe this behavior until I tried it.

Comment: This may well be duplicated but the duplicates are not good ones for this specific problem (caching specific `Integers`). Voted to reopen.

Comment: @gefei - It is described in JLS 5.1.7 (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7) at the end of the section.  Complete with a rationale.

Comment: I agree with @Bathsheba this question is not a duplicate of the ones provided.

Comment: Please open this question! @StephenC sir please take ur time and elaborate, as I'm new to java I will also go through it.

Comment: Sorry ... do you want me to copy an paste the answer from the other question?  Please explain what you don't understand.  There is no need to elaborate on an Answer that thoroughly answers your question already.

Comment: @Paul Hi paul.At first i too thought that this question is similar too string comparision but  Great lord it is not.You read it once again it is the peculiar behaviour of java.Thanks.

Comment: @AnilKumar yeah, sry. Thought it was just that usual BS about comparing objects. I've voted to reopen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an optimisation, the JVM caches some `Integer` references (those from -128 to +127) when it starts up.

So an `Integer` equal to 40 will refer to one in that cache. That's why two references with value 40 will compare equal: they are both referring to the same cached object.

Since 400 is outside the cached range, an `Integer` reference set to 400 will not refer to a cached object, so two references with that value will not compare equal.

Comment: To add to this, == works in the cached case (40 in your example), because both instances x and y refer to the exact same object in the cache, whereas when you create x=400 and y=400, they refer to different objects in memory.

Answer (score 2):

This is because of the Java Integer cache. When a number is within the cache the reference is intilized to one from the cache instead of making a new object. In your case, 40 is within the cache so the object references are the same, but 400 is outside of the cache so the objects are not the same reference.See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3130348/5117760).