# Assigning Integer to Object allowed but assigning Integer array to Object array not allowed?

Tags: java, arrays, object, inheritance

I was doing a reading on how child class objects can be assigned to parent class containers. There are 3 scenarios, listed below. For collections, arrays and plain objects. I got confused between the three scenarios about how & why all three are handled differently in Java. Is there a simple explanation for below scenarios, please? They seem to be very basic java concepts, don't know why are confusing me.

1. This gives compile time error.

   ```
   List<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<Integer>();//compile time error
   ```
2. But, this is allowed

   ```
   Object object = new Integer(9);
   object = 1.2;// no run time error
   ```
3. But this is not? (though, technically compiler allows but we get a runtime error)

   ```
   Object objectArr[] = new Integer[1];
   objectArr[0] = 1.2;// run time error (Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException: java.lang.Double)
   ```

Comment: What is the error you get on compile time for the first example?

Comment: This correct! Do Research on *covariance* and contravariance for Genesis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign something of type A to a variable of type B if A is a *subtype* of B. Broadly speaking, for non-primitive types, this means that A must support all the operations that B does.

Looking at your examples:

First:

```
List<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<Integer>();//compile time error
```

Right, because an `ArrayList<Integer>` is not a `List<Object>`; you cannot add an `Object` to it. Consider:

```
List<Object> l = new ArrayList<Object>();
List<Integer> l2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
l.add(new Object()); // ok
l2.add(new Object()); // not ok; `List<Integer>` doesn't support this.
```

So you see a `List<Integer>` (or an `ArrayList<Integer>`) is not a subtype of `List<Object>` - because it doesn't support all the same operations.

Next:

```
Object object = new Integer(9);
object = 1.2;// no run time error
```

In this case, the value `1.2` is auto-boxed into the wrapper type `Double` (full name `java.lang.Double`). As this is a subclass of `Object` the assignment then works fine. What is stored in the variable `object` is not the primitive `double` value 1.2, but rather a reference to a `Double` object which wraps the primitive value.

Finally:

```
Object objectArr[] = new Integer[1];
objectArr[0] = 1.2;// run time error (Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException: java.lang.Double)
```

This is the oddball case. Java considers an array of `Integer` to be a subtype of an array of `Object`, though by normal type theory this wouldn't be the case, since you can't store an `Object` (that isn't also an `Integer`) into such an array. On the other hand, an array of `Integer` does at least support all the other operations that an array of `Object` does - you can retrieve elements and be sure they are a subtype of `Object`; you can check the array length; etc. So, you can assign `new Integer[1]` - an `Integer` array - to a variable of type `Object[]`.

To make this form of sub-typing work, the `Integer` array needs to implement a "store `Object` element" operation similar to what `Object[]` implicitly supports. Since an `Integer[]` is only supposed to contain `Integer` objects, however, the store operation must fail - so you get an exception at runtime if you try to store something that isn't an `Integer`. In your example you're storing `1.2` which is auto-boxed to a `Double`, not an `Integer`.

Comment: Why "object = 1.2" is boxing but "objectArr[0] = 1.2"  not?

Comment: @KumarManish it _is_ also boxing. But it boxes to the `Double` type, and the array is an `Integer` array; a `Double` is not an `Integer`, so you can't store one in the array.

Comment: Array is an integer array so can't push in Double. Understood. But the same doesn't hold good for object when we do "Object object = new Integer(9)" ? How can we store double in "object" which is initialized with "new Integer(9)" , then? Something related to how "new Integer(9)" gets created in memory heap vs "new Integer[1]" ?

Comment: @KumarManish Reference-type variables in Java are references. You are initialising the `object` variable with a reference to an `Integer` and then replacing it with a reference to a `Double`. In the case of the array you cannot replace an element value with an object of an incompatible type. A variable's dynamic type changes to whatever you assign to it, but eg the `object` variable always retains the _static_ type of `Object`. An array element's static type also cannot be changed.

Answer (score 1):

1. `ArrayList<Integer>` is not an implementation of `List<Object>`. `ArrayList<Object>` is.
2. You create an `Integer` and assign it to an `Object` variable. You cannot assign a `double` to an `Object`, since `double` is a primitive type and does not inherit from `Object`. You could assign a `Double` though.
3. You create an `Integer` array of a single element and assign it to a variable of `Object` array. Then you try to assign a value to your `Integer` element, which is not an `Integer`.

EDIT:

As davman explained, my answer on 2. is incorrect, object = 1.2; is actually valid code due to [boxing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130311/weird-integer-boxing-in-java).

Further explanation:

1. Any `Integer` is an `Object`, but an `Object` is not necessarily an `Integer`. You can expect to be able to add any `Object` into a `List<Object>`, but you can add only `Integer` values into an `ArrayList<Integer>`. Now, if you assign an `ArrayList<Integer>` to a `List<Object>`, then later you might try to add a `Double` to `List<Object>`, for instance, which is perfectly valid with `List<Object>`. But since you stored an `ArrayList<Integer>`, where the operation is invalid, the operation would fail. This failure is due to the inconsistency of assigning `ArrayList<Integer>` to `List<Object>`. The compiler defends you from this inconsistency with the compile time error.
2. Even though you have an `Object` array, that does not change the fact that you have an `Integer` inside it. And you try to assign a value to that `Integer`, which is invalid to `Integer`s.

Comment: Your answer for (1) is good but could do with some added explanation (why is `ArrayList<Integer>` not a `List<Object>` - what operations doesn't it support)? Your answer for (2) is incorrect because you don't take boxing into account. For (3) again a little more detail would be nice.

Comment: @davmac, thank you for the constructive criticism. I will edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In your first line you must write:

```
List<? extends Object> objectList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

then it works. `? extends Object` means the List contains elements which extends the Object, e.g. Integer.

if you use the `?` operator as given here, then you do not have an `add` method anymore. So you need first to add all the elements in your `ArrayList` and assign it later:

```
ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>();
al.add(3);
...
List<? extends Object> objectList = al;
```