# Why do these two number comparisions not work the same way?

Tags: java, integer, wrapper

```
Integer i3 = 10;
Integer i4 = 10;
System.out.println(i3 == i4);
Integer i5 = 1000;
Integer i6 = 1000;
System.out.println(i5 == i6);
```

I got output for the above code as,

> ```
> true
> false
> ```

I can understand how `i3==i4`, but what is the reason to `i5==i6` become `false`.

Comment: Yup, this is a flaw in Java. A big one in my opinion.

Comment: @L.Spillner Oops, shall I reopen and hope someone else closes to that one?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3130348/8181750

Comment: @Bathsheba No sorry. I still ahd the wrong link stored in my clipboard.

Comment: @Bathsheba, why do you think it's a big flaw?