# Any difference in creating Timestamp using constructor vs from an Instant

Tags: java

I was wondering is there any difference or which one is better between these two in creating a current sql `timestamp`

```
java.sql.Timestamp t1 = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());

java.sql.Timestamp t2 = Timestamp.from(Instant.now());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which one is better depends on your requirements. If you want more than milliseconds precision, use `Timestamp.from(Instant.now())`. However, you should bear the following points in mind:

1. Your system clock almost certainly does not have nanosecond accuracy. You will be lucky if it is within a millisecond of actual UTC.
2. Your DBMS probably holds SQL timestamp values with less than nanosecond precision. For example, PostgreSQL has microsecond precision.
3. Using the nanoseconds from `Instant.now()` is only useful when you compare two such instants to see which one came first. Even then, it is not 100% guaranteed that Instant uses a monotonic clock (so not 100% guaranteed that if you call `Instant.now()` twice, you'll get a higher value from the second call). However, on a well maintained Linux system running `ntpd`, your system clock *should* be monotonic and therefore, in those circumstances, you *could* use the timestamp to determine which event came after which.

Answer (score 3):

The second instance t2 gets you also the nanoseconds, so it is more precise. The first one stops at milliseconds.

t1 console log:
2023-09-14 16:44:51.055

t2 console log:
2023-09-14 16:44:51.057259

Answer (score 2):

I know that there is only one not significant difference:

`Timestamp.from(Instant.now())` is more precise, as it can represent timestamps with a resolution of nanoseconds.

`new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())` can only represent timestamps with a resolution of milliseconds.

Comment: This is true only for Java 9+. In Java 8, `Instant.now` has only milliseconds, with zero microseconds/nanoseconds.

Answer (score 2):

## Moot question

Several good Answers already. But none mention the most important thing: Your Question is moot.

The terribly flawed `java.sql.Timestamp` class was years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310 for Java 8+. Specifically replaced by `OffsetDateTime` for JDBC (database access), and by `Instant` for more general purposes.

[JDBC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) 4.2+ requires all [drivers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) to support *java.time*. [Jakarta Persistence](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_Persistence) (JPA) and [Hibernate](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernate_(framework)) have been updated to support *java.time*.

So there is **no reason for you to be constructing any `Timestamp`** objects. Do all your work in *java.time* classes.

### *java.time* with JDBC

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.now() ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

Retrieval:

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myReultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

### Converting legacy ↔ modern

You may need to interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*. You can convert back and forth between legacy and modern classes by calling new conversion methods added to the old classes.

```
Timestamp ts = java.sql.Timestamp.from( odt.toInstant() ) ;
```

And the other direction:

```
Instant instant = ts.toInstant() ;
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

By the way… Both `OffsetDateTime` and `Instant` resolve to nanoseconds. Be aware that many databases do not support such fine granularity. You can [truncate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#truncatedTo(java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit)) your *java.time* objects if need be.

Answer (score 1):

Sans any internal implementation differences, as long as you're talking about milliseconds then they are the same as they are both how many milliseconds from the epoch date and time (aka [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time#:%7E:text=Early%20definitions%20of%20Unix%20time,to%20avoid%20short%2Dterm%20overflow)) of 1970-01-01 00:00 UTC have elapsed.

Any delta time it takes to invoke the two calls is somewhat mitigated by calling twice in different order and then averaging.

```
long instant1 = Instant.now().toEpochMilli();
long system1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

long system2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
long instant2 = Instant.now().toEpochMilli();

System.out.println((system1 + system2)/2);
System.out.println((instant1 + instant2)/2);
```

prints something like

```
1694702273207
1694702273207
```

Comment: This is a good answer, and everything works fine, but would just like to remind readers that in the general case, if you want to get the average of two integers that could possibly be very large (not so in this particular case), it's safer to average using `n1 + (n2 - n1) / 2` in order to avoid the possibility of overflow.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the [source code](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.sql/share/classes/java/sql/Timestamp.java) there are indeed subtle differences in the implementation:

```
public static Timestamp from(Instant instant) {
    try {
        Timestamp stamp = new Timestamp(instant.getEpochSecond() * MILLIS_PER_SECOND);
        stamp.nanos = instant.getNano();
        return stamp;
    } catch (ArithmeticException ex) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(ex);
    }
}
```

vs

```
public Timestamp(long time) {
    super((time/1000)*1000);
    nanos = (int)((time%1000) * 1000000);
    if (nanos < 0) {
        nanos = 1000000000 + nanos;
        super.setTime(((time/1000)-1)*1000);
    }
}
```

In practice I'd say that none of those is significantly better or worse than the other(1). However, factory methods *may* allow for optimizations in future JDK versions (cf. [Weird Integer boxing in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3130311/4616087)) so I'd personally prefer `from`.

(1) Other answers mention the different resolution of nanos vs millis but that also depends on the system clock and more often than not does not make a difference in real-world code. It can also simply be remedied by using [`System.nanoTime()`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()).